# undefined reference to staticMetaObject

Tags: c++, qt

It looks like Qt is not handling the [Q_GADGET](https://github.com/qtproject/qtbase/blob/dev/src/corelib/kernel/qobjectdefs.h#L176) macro properly, because i am getting the error below. Anyone know why?

**ERROR:** *undefined reference to `Exception::staticMetaObject'*

**EDIT:** Later i found that the MOC doesn't generate moc_exception.cpp. Sometimes when i switch the compiler kit it compiles fine but than if i add another class that inherits Exception, it again doesn't work. The problem needs to be somewhere in MOC which ignores the Q_GADGET macro in some conditions?

I have Qt 5.5.0.

**project.pro**

```
CONFIG += c++11

QT += core
QT -= gui

SOURCES += \
    main.cpp

HEADERS += \
    nobject.h \
    exception.h
```

**nobject.h**

```cpp
#ifndef NOBJECT_H
#define NOBJECT_H

#include <QObject>

class NObject
{

    Q_GADGET

public:
    NObject() {}
    virtual ~NObject() {}

};

#endif // NOBJECT_H
```

**exception.h**

```cpp
#ifndef EXCEPTION_H
#define EXCEPTION_H

#include "nobject.h"

class Exception : public NObject
{

    Q_GADGET

public:
    Exception() {}
    virtual ~Exception() {}

};

#endif // EXCEPTION_H
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include "exception.h"

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    Exception nobject;

    std::cout << Exception::staticMetaObject.className() << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suspect running qmake might solve your problem. Remember to re-run qmake every time you add or remove *Q_GADGET* or *Q_OBJECT* macro to get moc tool to re-generate code for meta data.

I didn't find any problem in your code by looking it so I copy-pasted the code to my machine and built and ran it. It built ok after I added implementation for NObject constructor. I built and ran it successfully on Qt5 and Qt4, and the program printed *Exception* on the console.

Qt 5:

```
> ~/temp/qgadgettest$ qmake --version
QMake version 3.0
Using Qt version 5.2.1 in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu

> /temp/qgadgettest$ ./qgadgettest 
Exception
```

Qt 4:

```
> ~/temp/qgadgettest$ qmake-qt4 --version
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.6 in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu

> ~/temp/qgadgettest$ ./qgadgettest 
Exception
```

Comment: This is one that catches me out regularly.  By default, qmake adds a rule to make the Makefile when it's out of date from the project file.  But it doesn't know it needs to be updated when you add one of MOC's macros to a file in `$HEADERS`.  You should be able to `make -B Makefile` to force it.

Comment: And what if I don't use qmake?

Comment: The beef here is to invoke moc to generate code for newly added meta object. You can run moc manually too. If you write your Makefile by hand you can check here how to automate moc running: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/moc.html . In cmake you use specific commands in cmakelists file and re-run cmake to regenerate meta data: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/cmake-manual.html

Answer (score 1):

In my environment, this code is correct. But I have added to the body of the constructor NObject.